# Use Radio Buttons to Increase a value in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to set up a voting process where there are 20 sets of two radio buttons you can select from.  Then when a "vote" button is clicked I can collect the values of the selected buttons and add +1 to their respective database cells.

I am new to MySql and am struggling...

The database Table looks like..

```
ID      Park          Votes
1       Zion          0
2       Grand Canyon  0
3       Arches        0
4       Canyonlands   0
5       Yosemite      0
6       Yellowstone   0
```

The HTML form

```
<form action="/databases/save.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="match1" value="1" />Zion
    <input type="radio" name="match1" value="1" />Grand Canyon
    <input type="radio" name="match2" value="1" />Arches
    <input type="radio" name="match2" value="1" />Canyonlands
    <input type="radio" name="match3" value="1" />Yosemite
    <input type="radio" name="match3" value="1" />Yellowstone
    <input type="image" src="/graphics/logo.png" />
</form>
```

And the save.php file

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['match1'])){
        $match1 = $_POST['match1'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO results () VALUES ('1')");
    }
    ?>
```

I am getting thrown off by how to get the selected radio and apply a +1 to the correct table cell.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect for `radio` inputs. If you want the user to select only one park, all inputs must have the same name. Use the `value` attribute of the radio input to store the ID of the park (from the MySQL table):

```
<form action="/databases/save.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="1" />Zion
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="2" />Grand Canyon
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="3" />Arches
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="4" />Canyonlands
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="5" />Yosemite
  <input type="radio" name="match" value="6" />Yellowstone
  <input type="image" src="/graphics/logo.png" />
</form>
```

The selected value for that input will be returned as `$_POST['match']` if one item was selected or else `$_POST['match']` will not be set at all.

So on your `save.php` page you can update your table like this (assuming your table is named "parks_table"):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['match'])) {
  mysql_query( 'UPDATE `parks_table` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE ID = '.$_POST['match'] );
}
?>
```

Since you seem to be starting with PHP and MySQL please read: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: You answer is more complete and accurate. I will withdraw mine.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <button type="submit" name="vote" id="vote" value=" ' .  $row['candidate_position'] . ' "  class="btn btn-success">CAST VOTE</button>
     <?php

$vote = $_POST['vote'];

if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
 mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbCandidates SET candidate_votes=candidate_votes+1 WHERE  position_id='$vote'");
 echo "string";
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```